# How to can I Transfer Data from One ASP.Net Application to another ASP.Net Application?

Tags: asp.net

How to can I Transfer Data from One ASP.Net Application to another ASP.Net Application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data with storing data in cookies.
Or you can also store data and retrieve it with using session state event of C#.

Comment: Found the solution..!